# Excel: Named Ranges based on cell Values

Tags: microsoft-excel, named-ranges

Is it possible to **change the name of a Named Range based on the Value of a Cell?**

ie. A1 = `NameOfRange`

If A1 changes to `NewNameOfRange`, how could this update the name?

Comment: With VBA code that's probably possible, but without it, I'm pretty sure it isn't! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your cell `A1` contains the name of the range in question you can reference the range with the `INDIRECT` function, e.g. `=SUM(INDIRECT(A1))` to calculate its sum.

Comment: Kindly edit your answer in a convenient way to help OP